# Display Controller data in view in liferay

Tags: jsp, view, controller, liferay

I looked at in everywhere and couldn't find it, or my search was not good enough. Anyways, here goes my question. How do I display and/or transfer data from a controller to the view jsp file in liferay MVC? i.e. if a variable "var" contains the value "This is a variable" in the controller java class, how do I display and/or access it in the jsp file? or to make it simple... How can we pass a value from controller to the jsp view in liferay MVC?

Thank for any suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of options to achive this depending on the framework you use.
(Liferay MVC Portlet , spring portlets , JSF)

For this answer I assume you use the MVC Portlet:

Lets go with everyones favorite example hello world:

```
public class HelloWorldPortlet extends MVCPortlet{

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

        renderRequest.setAttribute("helloMessage", "Hello World");
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }


}
```

---

**Now this won't work out of the box!**

In your portlet.xml change:

```
<portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
```

To:

```
<portlet-class>**Your Package structure**.HelloWorldPortlet</portlet-class>
```

---

The view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<%-- Option A --%>
<h1>
    <c:out value="${helloMessage}" />
</h1>

<%-- Option B --%>
<% 
        String message = (String)request.getAttribute("helloMessage");
%>
<h1>
    <%= message %>
</h1>
```

---

Custom action:

View.jsp

```
<portlet:actionURL name="worldHello" var="worldpageURL" />

<aui:a href="${worldpageURL}">World hello</aui:a>

<h2><c:out value="${worldHello}"/></h2>
```

HelloWorldPortlet

```
public class HelloWorldPortlet extends MVCPortlet{

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

        renderRequest.setAttribute("helloMessage", "Hello World");
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }



    public void worldHello(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse renderResponse){
        request.setAttribute("worldHello", "World Hello");
    }
}
```

Based on your comments it would be best if you look into :

http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/documentation
Since JSF based portlet could be there main focus in the future

http://www.liferay.com/community/blogs?p_p_id=115&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_115_struts_action=%2Fblogs_aggregator%2Fview_entry&_115_entryId=13443886

Comment: Is the doView() function a compulsion to pass the value or can we use any function for the purpose?

Comment: doView() will be called when the portlet gets displayed on a page.

Comment: Ok, how can we initialize the RenderRequest object in another function? and Can we pass the value from that functino to the doView function for display ?

Comment: Im not sure if its a good idea to Initialize an RenderRequest object. Let Liferay create the object for you , you receive it in the doView() method then do your magic and then make a call the the baseclass. You will probally run into a problem if you do this yourself, since allot of conventions happen behind the scene.

Comment: Oh oh, the problem is I had to display the values dynamically and after a certain function is called with any number of pages, How can we use the doView for that conditon? Multiple controllers? Is it possible to have multiple portlet classes? or How do we create multiple controllers?

Comment: updated my answer, its up to you to decide what framework is needed for your senario :-)

Comment: Hey, I am adding this new comment for another problem, can I send a List<String> object from request.setAttribute from Controller to View ?